# Error when starting the DolphinDB server outside of the server directory

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, dolphindb, dynamic-library

When I started the DolphinDB server from somewhere outside the server directory, I got the error ”error while loading shared libraries:libgfortran.so.3“ (see screenshot below):

[image]

The files are all complete. I didn’t get this error when I started the server with ./dolphindb under the server directory.

Comment: You made a lot of _statements_. Did you have a _question_ that you want answered?

Answer (score 0):

To run DolphinDB outside of its server directory, please configure the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the following command:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/DolphinDB/server/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```